# C++ Stop inputting text into 2D array once it reaches the end of the line

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files

Ive searched and re-read but I can't figure this one out. I am simply trying to input a text file into a [i][j] string array. Which it does fine, but i need it to stop inputting into the array once it gets to the end of the line and start putting the second line in the 2nd array stop at the end of the line and so on..

My file contains 4 separate lines that read.

This is line one.
This is line two.
This is line three.
This is line four.

And my code reads it and mostly does what i need it to. But it puts everything into the array until it runs out of room then continues to the next row. It doesn't stop once it reaches the end of line one. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arrayTextIn[25][25];
    ifstream textIn;
    textIn.open("sampleText.txt");

    for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<25; j++)
    {
        textIn >> arrayTextIn[i][j];
            if(arrayTextIn[i][j] == "\n") //This is where I dont know how to proceed.
                break;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<25; j++)
           cout << i << " " << j << " "<< arrayTextIn[i][j] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output but what i want is each line to start at a new [ith] row. Thanks for the help.
0 0 This
0 1 is
0 2 line
0 3 one.
0 4 This
0 5 is
0 6 line
0 7 two.
0 8 This
0 9 is
0 10 line
0 11 three.
0 12 This
0 13 is
0 14 line
0 15 four.
0 16
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-step process.

The first step is to read the input, one line at a time, this would be reading each line of text in the input file:

```
ifstream textIn;

textIn.open("sampleText.txt");

for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    std::string line;

    if (std::getline(textIn, line).eof())
        break;

    // Magic goes here.

}
```

So, what we've accomplished so far is read each line of input, up to the maximum of 25.

The second step is take each line of input, and divide it into whitespace-delimited words. This part goes where magic goes, above:

```
std::istringstream iline(line);

for(int j=0; j<25; j++)
{
    std::string word;

    if ((iline >> word).eof())
        break;

    arrayTextIn[i][j]=word;
}
```

You start by constructing an `istringstream`, which works exactly like `ifstream`, except that the input stream comes from a string.

Then, it's pretty much what you had originally, except now the scope is small enough to be easily handled with a single loop.

In conclusion: the way to approach a task of any moderate complexity is to divide it into two or more smaller task. Here, you take this relatively complicated task and turn it into two smaller, easier to implement tasks: first, reading each line of text, and, second, given a line of read text, divide each line into its individual words.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to maintain your design (2D-array) then this may be a fast solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  std::string line;
  std::getline(textIn, line);  // read the entire line

  if (textIn.eof()) {
    // if reach the end of file, then break the cycle.
    break;
  }

  if (line.size() > 0) {  // avoid empty lines
    int j = 0;
    size_t finder;

    // Cycle and looking for whitespace delimiters.
    while (finder = line.find(' '), finder != std::string::npos && j < 25) {
      // get a single word
      auto token = line.substr(0, finder);

      if (token != " ") {
        // if that word is not a simple white-space then save it in the array. You can also std::move if C++11
        arrayTextIn[i][j] = token;
        ++j;
      }

      // erase that part from the main line
      line.erase(0, finder + 1);
    }
  }
}
```